# No files were found with the provided path: No artifacts will be uploaded. Github Actions Fastlane

Tags: ios, github, github-actions, fastlane, building-github-actions

I'm following this tutorial on setting up CI/CD with github actions for a ios app. I want the action to build and deploy my ios app. I'm fairly sure I'm followed the directions, but when I trigger my action with a push, I get this error:

> Run actions/upload-artifact@v2
> Warning: No files were found with the provided path: /Users/runner/work/test.ipa
> /Users/runner/work/test/*.app.dSYM.zip. No artifacts will be uploaded.

**YML Code:-**

```
name: iOS binary build & upload

on:
 workflow_dispatch:
 push:

 jobs:
 deploy:
  runs-on: macos-latest
  steps:
 - uses: actions/checkout@v2

 - name: Set up ruby env
   uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
   with:
     ruby-version: 3.0.0
     bundler-cache: true


 - name: Upload app-store ipa and dsyms to artifacts
   uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
   with:
     name: app-store ipa & dsyms
     path: |
       ${{ github.workspace }}/ test.ipa
       ${{ github.workspace }}/*.app.dSYM.zip
```

I thought this error might have something to do with my build directory's location, but its in the standard place. Any thoughts on what this might be?

**Question:** Can someone please explain to me how to solve this and create .ipa, I've tried with above code but no results yet.

Can someone please explain to me How to get Progress?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't you missing a step where you create those files?